# "No command 'Not' found, did you mean: ..."? whenever I open a new shell

Tags: bash, 15.04

For some reason I now get the following output whenever I open a new terminal.

```
No command 'Not' found, did you mean:
 Command 'jot' from package 'athena-jot' (universe)
 Command 'hot' from package 'hopenpgp-tools' (universe)
 Command 'dot' from package 'graphviz' (main)
Not: command not found
```

There is nothing obvious in bashrc or my environment.  A grep for 'Not' turned up blank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, looks like a typo in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or `.profile`.

You can add `set -x` to the top and try again and it will give you more info.

Comment: Ah, found it... it's actually a bash completion for docker-compose!  I downloaded the file but entered the path incorrectly and it created a file containing "Not found".  Deleted it, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem in another file. `.git-completion.bash`

There was `Not found` in the file.
You just need to delete the line.

Maybe it will help someone.